# In Which situation MYISAM AND INNODB Engine should be used

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Give me some practical examples in which I can understand use of both myisam and innodb engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyISAM storage engine is clearly being phased out, and I expect it will eventually be removed from MySQL.

If you want to keep upgrading to newer version of MySQL, you should design your databases to *never* use MyISAM.

MyISAM does not support any of the following:

- ACID properties
- foreign keys
- transactions
- clustered index
- row-level locking
- concurrent updates
- crash recovery
- data caching (only indexes are cached; data is cached by the filesytem)
- partitioning (in MySQL 8.0)

MyISAM is receiving no improvements by the MySQL engineering team, as far as I know.

MyISAM is still used for the grant tables in the `mysql.*` schema as of MySQL 5.7, but in 8.0, those tables are all stored in InnoDB.

On my last project, I used MyISAM for only one table. The table stored 5 billion rows and it needed to be stored on a server with limited disk space with no plan or budget for upgrading. MyISAM stored this table in half the space than InnoDB (your case may get a different storage ratio, depending on data types, indexes, and other factors). Using MyISAM, I could store this table on the server until it could be upgraded. Using InnoDB, the table would have been too large.